# How can I add 3 line in html?

Tags: html, cs-cart

How can I add 3 line  in HTML?
Like attached photo

[image: reference]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: You mean columns?

Comment: Try to take a look at w3schools they have the solution to problems like these https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_three_columns.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `flexbox` like this:

```css
.row {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -.5rem;
  margin-left: -.5rem;
}

.col {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.list {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding:0;
}
.list li{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  padding-left:15px;
}
.list li:before{
  content:'>';
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
      <ul class="list">
         <li>Contact us</li>
         <li>about us</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
      <ul class="list">
         <li>Contact us</li>
         <li>about us</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col">column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to mack beside like contact us

Comment: cadd add html only or we must use css cod